# Android: Navigation Drawer slows down on adding Ongoing Notification

Tags: android, performance, android-service, android-notifications

I had created a foreground service. I am adding a ongoing notification in Notification Drawer. 
If I open Navigation Drawer on starting my service, it UI starts lagging.

```
 Intent contentIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    contentIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,contentIntent,0);

    Intent stopIntent = new Intent(this,Manager.class);
    stopIntent.setAction(Types.ACTION_STOP_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent stopServiceIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this,0,stopIntent,0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .setLights(0x008080, 100, 500)
            .setTicker(Types.NOTI_TITLE)
            .setContentTitle(Types.NOTI_TITLE)
            .setContentText(Types.NOTI_CONNECT_TEXT)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .addAction(0, "Tap here to Stop", stopServiceIntent)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setOngoing(true).build();
    startForeground(Types.SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_ID,notification);
```

Any ideas, why Navigation Drawer became slow ?

Comment: looks like you start service in the main thread. have you tried this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample?

Comment: The problem is not with service, it is with Notification, that I show. If I comment the code that shows notification, it works fine, but when I show notification in Status bar, it becomes slow.

Comment: When I pull down the status bar, the notification panel opens with a lag and frequent freezes, this happens only if I show notification from service.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, the resources I used in Notification were large. Making it smaller solved this.